# how to Run selenium code in different browser versions in same Node?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am trying to run one test on different version of browser exes present in node. How I can pass version info in code and how to configure node to accept those arguement?

Comment: How can you have different versions of browsers installed on one node? If you manage somehow to install 2 or more different version of a browser on a single node, how would you tell which one the driver will use?

Comment: Otherwise the way remote webDriver works is: 1. When registering a node on the hub in the config file you're passing to the hub an argument version. This version can be whatever you define, for ex: "potato". When initiating a remote web driver, you're calling the hub with a capabilities parameter, which contains your browser version "potato".

Comment: I can have different binaries on one node and refer their path.. my question also the same, how to tell which driver to use via code ?

Comment: exactly @BorisStoyanov how can I write that Config file and call a version to run from a node? I haven't found any doc on that apart from this https://gist.github.com/krmahadevan/1106418

Comment: This is the correct config file, what is the issue you are facing here?

Comment: @pArAs I want to configure different binaries in config file and call them from my script !~

Comment: you want to setup a node with different browser versions right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For running different browser versions on same node, you need to follow below steps.

> Install all the required browser versions on the node machine in case of `Firefox` browser and in case of  `ChromeDriver` or `IEDriver` Keep different binary versions.

Now you need to mention all the browser version in the `node_config` file which you have referred in your comment [NodeConfig](https://gist.github.com/krmahadevan/1106418).

e.g.:- you can mention different browser versions in your `node_config` file as mentioned below, I've used 2 different firefox versions.

```
{
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "maxInstances": 3,
      "version": 40,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "maxInstances": 3,
      "version":38, 
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
}
```

Now you can launch your node with the same config and you would be able to see 2 different browser versions on your `Selenium Grid` console.

[image: Selenium Grid Console]

Once you are able to setup your node, you can just run the code on your Grid hub and it will take care of browser distribution.

Comment: how would you be sure which browser initiated from the driver?

Comment: On same node, its not possible. Hub will automatically allot the browser based upon the availability. This can be achieved using multiple nodes.

Comment: Just one thing, where are we configuring different driver path in config? as after request comes for specific version it should execute on that particular driver.

Comment: You can mention it in the command line when you are invoking the node with this config.